# MySQL Couting duplicates of duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database filled with orders, with consist of an `id` and a `customerName`. What i'm trying to do is, finding how many of different order sizes is made. If a customer makes multiple orders will multiple rows containing the same `customerName`

I would like an output which looks somewhat like this:

```
+------------+----------+
| size       | quantity |
+------------+----------+
| 1          |      321 |
| 2          |      148 |
| 3          |       98 |
| 4          |       63 |
| 5          |       22 |
| 6          |        3 |
+------------+----------+
```

Edit 1:

```
+------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(6) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| signupDate       | date            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| customerName     | varchar(128)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Please provide your current table schema to help answer.

Comment: For id you have in col 3 "Null NO" and col 5 "Default NULL" what gives?

Comment: Gurwinder Singh, I mean, I need to see how many orders customers places at once. for example i want to know, how many have made an order of four, or how many have made order of two. I'm not sure if that made it more clear?

Comment: @Marichyasana I'm reading in the database from a third-party, so I'm insured the data is always complete. But you're right, it wouldn't hurt securing it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
size,count(1)
from
(
select customerName,count(1) as size from table group by customerName
) tmp group by  size
```

if this what you want?

Comment: I tried using it, but i get error message saying: Unknown column 'size' in 'field list', did i misunderstand how to use it?

Comment: i changed the sql,can you try it again?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have another table for orders that shows the size and quantity

ID, OrderNo, Size, Qty

in that case this query may help

```
select Size, SUM(Qty) as Qty 
From Orders
GROUP BY Size
```

Comment: I don't. it wouldn't be a practical way of doing it for my use case. I need to track each order as a seperate entity.

Comment: so where do u get the size and quantities from?!

Comment: asmgx, If a customer has made multiple orders, there will be multiple rows with the same name. I need to read how many duplicates there is for each customer, and then count what the sizes of these duplicates are

Comment: then i think the answer above this one is the right thing to do